# apache 443 connection refused error

Tags: apache-2.4, firewall, rackspace

so i'm running into a very funny, frustrating, and odd issue.

I have a RackSpace webserver running a webiste. Lets calls it `dummy.com`.

`http://dummy.com` is accessible on port `80` no problem. But accessing `https://dummy.com` gives me a `This site can't be reached` error on Chrome and similar on FireFox.

But what is confusing is that `https://1.11.111.1111` works (meaning if i access the site via its IP i'm able to access it)

this is the `VirtualHost` config I'm using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dummy.com
        ServerAlias  www.dummy.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.dummy.com

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/www.dummy.com>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName dummy.com
        ServerAlias  www.dummy.com 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.dummy.com
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/www.dummy.com>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ...

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/ssl/DUMMY.COM.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/ssl/dummy_com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/ssl/ov_chain.txt
</VirtualHost>
```

I had a thought that maybe the domain isn't being picked up on port `443` but that would be true for port `80` on this config.

So another question, because this is a server hosted on `RackSpace` is there a firewall setting in the manager that would be the cause of this issue? I'm stumped on this =(

oh, also this is the `netstat -tnlp` snippet

`tcp6       0      0 :::25          :::*           LISTEN      1670/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443         :::*           LISTEN      9013/apache2`

and `ss -tnlp | grep :80`

`LISTEN     0      128                      :::80                      :::*      users:(("apache2",9025,4),("apache2",9020,4),("apache2",9019,4),("apache2",9018,4),("apache2",9017,4),("apache2",9016,4),("apache2",9013,4))`

`ss -tnlp | grep :443`

`LISTEN     0      128                      :::443                     :::*      users:(("apache2",9025,6),("apache2",9020,6),("apache2",9019,6),("apache2",9018,6),("apache2",9017,6),("apache2",9016,6),("apache2",9013,6))`

edit: here is the apache logs when the server starts:

```
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.646647 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 10085] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'dummy.com:443'
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.647104 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10085] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.647176 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 10085] AH01914: Configuring server dummy.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.647722 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10085] ssl_engine_init.c(791): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (3 CA certificates)
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.647742 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10085] ssl_engine_init.c(328): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.647750 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10085] ssl_engine_init.c(838): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.647952 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10085] ssl_util_ssl.c(407): AH02412: [dummy.com:443] Cert matches for name 'dummy.com' [subject: CN=dummy.com,OU=Secure Link SSL,OU=IT,O=Dummy Corp,street=123 Happy Ave,L=Some City,ST=XX,postalCode=12345,C=US / issuer: CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2,O=Network Solutions L.L.C.,L=Herndon,ST=VA,C=US / serial: 501C094D916AE8257C96F3C794F0A10B / notbefore: Oct  6 00:00:00 2018 GMT / notafter: Sep 28 23:59:59 2020 GMT]
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.647988 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10085] ssl_engine_init.c(893): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.682709 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 10086] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'dummy.com:443'
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.683385 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10086] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.683569 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 10086] AH01914: Configuring server dummy.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.684012 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10086] ssl_engine_init.c(791): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (3 CA certificates)
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.684085 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10086] ssl_engine_init.c(328): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.684149 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10086] ssl_engine_init.c(838): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.684333 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10086] ssl_util_ssl.c(407): AH02412: [dummy.com:443] Cert matches for name 'dummy.com' [subject: CN=dummy.com,OU=Secure Link SSL,OU=IT,O=Dummy Corp,street=123 Happy Ave,L=Some City,ST=XX,postalCode=12345,C=US / issuer: CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2,O=Network Solutions L.L.C.,L=Herndon,ST=VA,C=US / serial: 501C094D916AE8257C96F3C794F0A10B / notbefore: Oct  6 00:00:00 2018 GMT / notafter: Sep 28 23:59:59 2020 GMT]
[Sun Oct 07 11:09:12.684392 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 10086] ssl_engine_init.c(893): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
```

thanks guys

Comment: What is the real domain name?

Comment: sorry to ask, but its for a client and i'm not sure they like for me to share specific information about the issue. is there any other info i can provide?

Comment: I am having to guess a bit, but it looks like an SNI / certificate issue. Without being able to follow the negotiation, it is hard to tell. You can run the failing request (FQDN) through [Redbot](https://redbot.org/?), and see what you get. Also, you should run it through [Qualys](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to see what returns.

Comment: for Redbot i get - Connection error (Transport endpoint is not connected) and for Qualys - Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server

Comment: Now it sounds like you don't have your DNS A record set. Do you? Can you connect to the `http` (not `https`) site with the FQDN?

Comment: ya, http is ok, https is what throws these errors

Comment: Try those same tests with the "Alias" FQDN.

Comment: but like i stated, accessing the https via the IP will load, it will ask me to accept the unsecure cert.

Comment: the www and non www give the same result.

Comment: What do your access logs show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a concept of so called Security Groups in Rackspace.
Login to Rackspace console, click on your server and scroll down to "Network and Security groups".
Another possibility is firewall on your host (`iptables -L` assuming it's one of the RedHat derivatives).
You can test if port 443 is open from outside with nmap or nc, you obviously need to be on remote host for it so you can see if you can establish TCP session towards port 443.